Sue prosecutor for son murder trial
I want to know can I sue the city attorney office for mishandling the prosecution of my son's murder case. They gave the defendant a plea deal and dropped the murder 1 charge and armed criminal action charge. After he had been held in custody prior to his trial this year for the past 6yrs with a 400,000 cash only bond.

You don't have a case against the prosecutor. But you may be able to get some additional justice by suing the perpetrator for unlawful death.

@Barmar Somehow, I doubt that someone who's been in prison for six years is going to have very many assets for a lawsuit to take.

@nick012000 True. It worked better in the OJ Simpson case.

Remember that the prosecutor's "client" is the state (or federal) government. They're not working for you individually, and your personal sense of justice is not their primary concern. Plea deals are common. Would you have felt better if they pursued the murder 1 charge and lost?

@Barmar Didn't really work that well in OJ's case either. Reportedly, Goldman's family got $133k of $33.5 million.

@user71659 Ouch! I just looked it up, and apparently much of his wealth after the trials was in his home and retirement funds, both of which are protected from creditors in FL. So both the rich and poor can be effectively judgement-proof, just by different means.

A prosecutor has absolute immunity from civil liability for his or her prosecutorial conduct. You can't sue the prosecutor.

Besides the obvious answer, "No," you may have victim's/survivor's rights in your jurisdiction.  These may or may not have remedies if the prosecutor did not follow the law.

Here is a guideline for Montana. The section titled "Coping with the criminal justice system" is relevant.

Not only do prosecutors have immunity, but in this case, the prosecutor didn't do anything wrong. Prosecutors have every right to make plea deals, and they do so all the time. In fact, the DA could have chosen not to pursue the case at all, and this still wouldn't constitute misconduct (unless it was for an inappropriate reason, such as bribery).
I completely understand why this is upsetting to you, but you can't sue someone just because you are mad at them.

Thank you everyone for your assistance and comments
